# Join tables/get values via foreignkeys going from bottom to top (using a where-clause IN array)? (See example)

Tags: sql, postgresql

With three example tables:

```
A: pk_a, name  
B: pk_b, name, fk_a  
C: pk_c, name, fk_b
```

How is it possible to go from bottom to top/parent or join/get the corresponding table A and B rows using only `pk_c` values?

Using asyncpg (python) it was not possible to use `WHERE pk_c IN (value1..valueN)` - so far I only have this:

```
conn.fetch("SELECT * FROM C WHERE pk_c = any($1::int[])", data_list)
```

and not competent enough to know where to go from here. Using left joins I can see how to go from top to bottom (atleast using two tables, not so sure about the SQL with three tables or several left joins), but not from bottom and up and at the same time getting several values in `WHERE`.
Could someone help me get going with this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What does *"using only `pk_c` values"* mean? Join doesn't really care about "direction" in a "top to bottom" or "bottom to top" sense, other than there isn't any need to use an outer join in a "bottom to top" scenario because you cannot have a "child" row without a "parent" in a relational graph that is enforcing "parent exists before child can exist". While a parent may lack any children and thus be a candidate for use of an OUTER join to ensure the childless parent stays present in the result, the fact that a child cannot exist without some parent means that child -> parent can just be INNER

Comment: @CaiusJard Previously I have tested ORM's but never understood what was going on beneath, so don't know the exact, proper terms so it is difficult for me to discuss what I mean. But with several primary keys belonging to table C the goal is to also get the values in table B and A? So now I only have the relevant rows in C, which contains the relevant foreignkey/id to rows in B, that in turn will have the relevant foreignkey/id to the relevant row in A? How does the SQL look like doing all this in one go, if possible?

Comment: I don't think your query is specifically SQL/PG, it's more a "how do I pass a list of ints to a where clause predicate using <insert name of your ORM here>?" - perhaps reword it and tag the ORM

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to avoid ORM's (for the rest of time, lol)

Comment: Not really a python dev so I have little experience of how this might be done there, but have answered from a C# perspective; if all else fails, you can literally build your SQL string using concat, start with a stub of `WHERE pk_c IN(@param1` and concatenate on N number of `,@paramN`, changing N each tme, one for each item in the array, and add a parameter value for the named parameter just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by  *using only pk_c values* means "I only have C ID values" and not "I'm not allowed to mention any primary key column other than C's anywhere in the SQL", you can just do the joins (any order)

```
SELECT *
FROM
  a 
  INNER JOIN b ON a.pk_a = b.fk_a
  INNER JOIN c ON b.pk_b = c.fk_b
WHERE
  c.pk_c IN (...)
```

If you're strugging to use IN with your query library that's more like a limitation of the library than any fault in SQL: IN expects a list of values and they cannot be parameterized as a single list. You cannot say:

```
WHERE x IN (@someParameter)
```

And then pack an array into @someparameter in your client side code, unless the library you use specifically supports seeing an array and splitting it out/modifying the SQL to be like this (for a 3-long array):

```
WHERE x IN (@someParameter1,@someParameter2,@someParameter3)
```

And then providing value `array[0]` into `@someparameter1`, `array[1]` into `@someparameter2`.

If the library of choice doesn't do that (or you're not using a library), you can

- do it yourself - concatenate repeatedly a new parameter placeholder onto your IN list, and provide a value for it from the array
- pass the data to the DB another way, such as turning it into a JSON array string, sending a single string parameter to the DB (with the json inside) and getting the DB to unpack the JSON into a list of values
- take the dangerous approach of "it's an array of ints; i'll concat them in directly because in this case it's not an SQL injection hack risk" - don't do it with an array of strings though..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM "C"
LEFT JOIN "B" ON "fk_b" = "pk_b"
LEFT JOIN "A" ON "fk_a" = "pk_a"
WHERE
    "pk_c" IN (2, 3, 5)
```

Because of the `LEFT JOIN` you will also get a row in the result if there is a row in C that does not have a matching row in "B". Same for the relation from "B" to "A". But since you mention parent/child relations that is probably never the case and then an `INNER JOIN` would also work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I disagree. It would only do that, if the condition would refer to `pk_a`. But as it refers only to `pk_c` the OUTER join remains intact, i.e. there can be a row with data from table C without data from B or A.

Comment: sorry, I misread the query I thought table C was one of the outer joined ones.

Answer (score 0):

You join the foreign keys to the primary keys.

Since the criteria are on C, you can start with C.
But if it's only INNER JOIN's, then the order of the joins doesn't really matter.
Postgresql will try to use the fastest methods to get the data anyhow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM C AS c
JOIN B AS b ON b.pk_b = c.fk_b
JOIN A AS a ON a.pk_a = b.fk_a
WHERE c.pk_c = ANY($1::int[])
```

If you want all of C, regardless if there's a fk_b or fk_a.
Then you can simply use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM C AS c
LEFT JOIN B AS b ON b.pk_b = c.fk_b
LEFT JOIN A AS a ON a.pk_a = b.fk_a
WHERE c.pk_c = ANY($1::int[])
```